# Two Dimensional List Loop

Tags: c#, list, for-loop

I am looping through a `List<List<Shape>>` object and checking if the horizontally and vertically adjacent objects are the same:

```
        for (int x = 0; x < grid.Columns.Count; x++)
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < grid.Columns[x].Count; y++)
            {
                if (y != grid.Columns[x].Count - 1)
                {
                    if (grid.Columns[x][y].Column == grid.Columns[x][y + 1].Column)
                    {
                        if (!shapesToDestroy.Contains(grid.Columns[x][y]))
                        {
                            shapesToDestroy.Add(grid.Columns[x][y]);
                        }
                        if (!shapesToDestroy.Contains(grid.Columns[x][y + 1]))
                        {
                            shapesToDestroy.Add(grid.Columns[x][y + 1]);
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (x != grid.Columns.Count - 1)
                {
                    if (grid.Columns[x][y].Column == grid.Columns[x + 1][y].Column)
                    {
                        if (!shapesToDestroy.Contains(grid.Columns[x][y]))
                        {
                            shapesToDestroy.Add(grid.Columns[x][y]);
                        }
                        if (!shapesToDestroy.Contains(grid.Columns[x + 1][y]))
                        {
                            shapesToDestroy.Add(grid.Columns[x + 1][y]);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

However, I always seem to get a `ArgumentOutOfRange` on

```
if (grid.Columns[x][y].Column == grid.Columns[x][y + 1].Column)
```

and

```
if (grid.Columns[x][y].Column == grid.Columns[x + 1][y].Column)
```

Before indexing these, I am performing a check as you can see to make sure that I do not get a `ArgumentOutOfRange`, but here I am. When I look at the index which is being `+ 1`, it appears to be well under the size of the collection.

Can anyone see the obvious mistake and where I am going horribly wrong?

**UPDATE**
I updated the code by changing the checks for X and Y to:

```
if (x < grid.Columns.Count - 1)
```

and

```
if (y < grid.Columns[x].Count - 1)
```

I still get the same error.

**FYI** - The size of the collection is always the same. The size is: X = 5 and Y = 10

Comment: Whats the values of x/y when it falls over? (and values of counts)

Comment: Have all the inner lists the same length or can they be different?

Comment: The lengths are the same always: X = 5 and Y = 10

Comment: why are you comparing the field Column grid.Columns[x][y].Column == grid.Columns[x][y + 1].Column, and not only the elements grid.Columns[x][y] == grid.Columns[x][y + 1] ? is that on purpose?

Comment: The grid you use is of what type? List<> has no property Columns. Maybe the directions of the two dimensions are mixed up...

Comment: There's no multithreading going on is there? Any other thread changing `grid`?

Comment: Grid is the class name and Columns is the name of the List<List<Shape>> object. There i no multi threading. I am only check the above vertical and horizontal elementals and ignoring diagonal elements

Comment: If `Columns` is a `List<List<Shape>>`, how can you do this: `grid.Columns[x + 1][y].Column`? `Column` is not a member of `Shape`.

Comment: Column is also an int field within Shape. Sorry my naming is a little off.

Answer (score 1):

```
 if (x != grid.Columns.Count - 1)
```

should be

```
if (x < grid.Columns.Count - 1)
```

Comment: Oops, well spotted. In that case, should I not just be doing < and not <=. Both ways throw the error as well

Comment: probably, sorry its still early here :)

Answer (score 1):

since y is iterated from 0 to the maximum index of the list the operation
 `grid.Columns[x][y + 1]` 
will attempt to access an element with a higher index than what is currently in the list. If you want to keep the code above you should change the loop to only iterate to

```
for (int x = 0; x < grid.Columns.Count-1; x++)
{
     for (int y = 0; y < grid.Columns[x].Count-1; y++)
     {
     }
}
```

Comment: This will lead to a different functionality of the loop.

Comment: since he/she is comparing the current element with the next one he/she will compare all elements in the loop using this too, since the iteration will reach the second to last element, and it will access the  +1th index from the if cases

Comment: But will this still work when keeping in mind that I need to check if the object to the right and above are the same as the currently indexed one? Will this functionality still work?

Comment: This also gives me the same error. ArgumentOutOfRangeException on the X

Comment: changed both x and y? then i'm confused

Comment: Yes. I changed both and I still get the above mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

I tried running your code, and i think you could get the functionality that you are looking for stripping it down to:

```
for (int x = 0; x < grid.Count; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < grid[x].Count; y++)
        {
            if (grid[x].Count > y && grid[x][y] == grid[x][y + 1])
            {
                if (!shapesToDestroy.Contains(grid[x][y]))
                {
                    shapesToDestroy.Add(grid[x][y]);
                }
                if (!shapesToDestroy.Contains(grid[x][y + 1]))
                {
                    shapesToDestroy.Add(grid[x][y + 1]);
                }
            }

            if (grid.Count > x && grid[x+1].Count > y && grid[x][y] == grid[x + 1][y])
            {
                if (!shapesToDestroy.Contains(grid[x][y]))
                {
                    shapesToDestroy.Add(grid[x][y]);
                }
                if (!shapesToDestroy.Contains(grid[x + 1][y]))
                {
                    shapesToDestroy.Add(grid[x + 1][y]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**
Could also remove the second if in both of the cases since you have already tested that they are equal, doesn't really matter though since it won't change the result. Would just improve performance a tiny bit

Comment: and that runs without any errors for me in a list<list<object>> with size 5x10

Comment: I still get the Range exception. I looked in to the grid one of the inner arrays is 11 and not 10 :\

Comment: added check for list size in the code so that it will run anyways, still maybe then you should check the construction of the list, and not the looping

Answer (score 0):

it seems that your if condition does not seems correct

Try this

```
 if (y < grid.Columns[x].Count - 1)
instead of 
 if (y != grid.Columns[x].Count - 1)
```

Comment: But that would break everything and ignore indexes 0's for X and Y.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your arrays are jagged. And the individual subarrays do not have the same length.
That could be a reason for getting an ArgumentOutOfRange-Exception in:

```cs
if (grid.Columns[x][y].Column == grid.Columns[x + 1][y].Column)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate the meaning of jaggered in this context, how it may have become jaggered and how I can fix the problem?

Comment: Jagged array = nested array with different lengths of its subarrays. You should inspect your arrays while debugging to determine if this is the case.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a foreach loop? then you won't have problems with the array out of bounds? Unless you are going for speed. You can use and then nest them as above.

```
foreach (int key in values.Keys)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} is assigned to key: {1}", values[key], key);
}
```